# If selenium hosted in server can it use the GoogleChrome webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, server, selenium-chromedriver, hosting

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium import webdriver

opsi = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opsi.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
opsi.add_argument('disable-infobars')
opsi.add_argument('start-maximized')
opsi.add_argument('disable-notifications')
opsi.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
**opsi.add_argument('--headless=new')**
caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "eager"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps,
service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=opsi)
driver.get(url)
```

Hi, I am very new to Selenium and never hosted any website before, when I used the `driver.get(url)` locally the **GoogleChrome Browser** must be installed to run the driver.get(url) right?

but if I want to host my project online and want the hosted website can use the function driver.get(url), the server will not have **Google Chrome Browser** installed right?
Will the driver.get(url) still function?
If not how I can do to let Selenium run driver.get(url) function?

Comment: you need to install Chrome on the server along with any other dependencies.  (better to use HTMLUnit if you can... )  You might also consider using a grid server and white-listing your server's IP to make remote calls to it.